# DropDown Value Selected Value

Tags: javascript

Can we post a form with a dropdown value through ajax as document.getElementById(dropdown).value as the selected value of drop down , Or is it neccessary that we should use selected.Index

Comment: You can use whatever makes the most sense to your application.

Comment: Can we post the selected value in dropdown  and then retrieve that correct value from database without using Selected.Index property along with document.getElementById...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "yes", but make sure that all options have a value attribute or property first, as not all browsers correctly report the [option value](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-value-OPTION) where no value has been set (i.e. instead of sending the content (text), they send nothing). That goes for normal form submission too.

Comment: how to make sure that property is there?

Comment: In a typical document, the value is provided as an in–line attribute in the markup. However, you might be dynamically creating elements, in which case you should add the value as a property of the DOM element. If you can't guarantee that, then you need to write your own "get option value" function that looks at the option value and if it's empty, gets the text. It is just simpler to just always give options a value.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no real difference.

I use `.value` if I have to, but generally I'll use jQuery and thus have the `.val()` function (or `.value()` in prototype)

Comment: it just say "use a library and you still won't know the answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use jquery.ajax, create an object with all the values (fields on form) you want to post and pass it to data: and set the type:"POST".

```
var valuestoPost = {field1:"val1", field2:"val2", dropdownval:$("#dropdownid").val()};
$.ajax({
    url: foopostURL,
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    data: valuestoPost,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    success:function (data){
       //operation on successful post
     },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    //operation on error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this JS function to make sure that all browsers getting the value:

```
function getDataForDropdown(colName){   
    var columnName = "";
    if ( columnName == null || columnName == '' )
    {
        var e = document.getElementById(colName);
        columnName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    }  

    if ( columnName == null || columnName == ''  || columnName.length==0)
    {
        columnName = document.getElementById(colName).value;
    }

    if ( columnName == null || columnName == ''  || columnName.length==0)
    {
        var select = document.getElementById(colName);
        columnName= select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        if ( columnName == null || columnName == '' || columnName.length==0)
        {
            columnName= select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
        }
    }  
    return columnName;  
}
```